# Insert Form Data Into MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm using a jQuery form to collect user data, and i am trying to insert the form values into the table `ptb_registrations`.

I am getting the error "error updating database"

Can someone show me where I am going wrong please, this should be fairly simple.

HTML:

```
<form action="process_registration.php" method="post" id="reg_form">

    <!-- #first_step -->
    <div id="first_step">
        <h1>SIGN UP FOR A FREE <span>ACTION-TIME.COM</span> ACCOUNT</h1>
        <div class="form">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="username" />
            <label for="username">At least 4 characters. Uppercase letters, lowercase letters and numbers only.</label>

            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="password" />
            <label for="password">At least 4 characters. Use a mix of upper and lowercase for a strong password.</label>

            <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" value="password" />
            <label for="cpassword">If your passwords aren’t equal, you won’t be able to continue with signup.</label>
        </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
        <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit_first" id="submit_first" value="" />
    </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->

    <!-- #second_step -->
    <div id="second_step">
        <h1>SIGN UP FOR A FREE <span>WEBEXP18</span> ACCOUNT</h1>

        <div class="form">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="first name" />
            <label for="firstname">Your First Name. </label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="last name" />
            <label for="lastname">Your Last Name. </label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="email address" />
            <label for="email">Your email address. We send important administration notices to this address. </label>                    
        </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
        <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit_second" id="submit_second" value="" />
    </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->

    <!-- #third_step -->
    <div id="third_step">
        <h1>SIGN UP FOR A FREE <span>WEBEXP18</span> ACCOUNT</h1>

        <div class="form">
            <select id="age" name="age">
                <option> 0 - 17</option>
                <option>18 - 25</option>
                <option>26 - 40</option>
                <option>40+</option>
            </select>
            <label for="age">Your age range. </label> <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->

            <select id="gender" name="gender">
                <option>Male</option>
                <option>Female</option>
            </select>
            <label for="gender">Your Gender. </label> <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->

            <select id="country" name="country">
                <option>United States</option>
                <option>United Kingdom</option>
                <option>Canada</option>
                <option>Serbia</option>
                <option>Italy</option>
            </select>
            <label for="country">Your country. </label> <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->

        </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
        <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit_third" id="submit_third" value="" />

    </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->

    <!-- #fourth_step -->
    <div id="fourth_step">
        <h1>SIGN UP FOR A FREE <span>WEBEXP18</span> ACCOUNT</h1>

        <div class="form">
            <h2>Summary</h2>

            <table>
                <tr><td>Username</td><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Password</td><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Email</td><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Name</td><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Age</td><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Gender</td><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Country</td><td></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>      <!-- clearfix --><div class="clear"></div><!-- /clearfix -->
        <input class="send submit" type="submit" name="submit_fourth" id="submit_fourth" value="" />            
    </div>

</form>
```

PHP / MYSQL:

```
<?php ob_start(); 

include '../includes/_config/connection.php'; 

$query="INSERT INTO ptb_registrations (ID,
     username,
     password,
     firstname,
     lastname,
     email,
     age,
     gender,
     country
 )
VALUES('NULL',
     '".$username."',
     '".$password."',
     '".$firstname."',
     '".$lastname."',
     '".$email."',
     '".$age."',
     '".$gender."',
     '".$country."'
)";
mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');
?>

<?php include ('includes/send_email/reg_email.php'); ?>

<? ob_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php will get you on the right track probably.

Comment: Why not check the error message? with or die(mysql_error());

Comment: change `mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');` to `mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());` and post results.

Comment: What values are stored in your parameters? You don't show where you initialize them.   $username = $_POST["username"];

Comment: @uɐɥʇɐᴎ You can pass it as `NULL` or `'NULL'` or `"NULL"`.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to specifie the id value if its auto increment

try this

```
   $query="INSERT INTO ptb_registrations (
 username,
 password,
 firstname,
 lastname,
 email,
 age,
 gender,
 country

 )
VALUES(
'".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($firstname)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($lastname)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($age)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($gender)."',
'".mysql_real_escape_string($country)."'
)";
```

you should escape your values by `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 0):

If **ID** is Primary Key and Auto Increment then you do not need pass in query and use this query:

```
$query = " INSERT INTO ptb_registrations SET
username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."',
password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($password)."',
firstname = '".mysql_real_escape_string($firstname)."',
lastname = '".mysql_real_escape_string($lastname)."',
email = '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."',
age = '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."',
gender = '".mysql_real_escape_string($gender)."',
country = '".mysql_real_escape_string($country)."'";
```

Hope it will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove single quotes from null and use without quotes e.g. null

Comment: It shouldn't matter at all. If you even use like this `"NULL"` it should works.

Comment: @Mahdi: I think there is difference in 'null' and null

Comment: You can simply check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove column names and try, it works. Try something like this

```
INSERT INTO table_name values(NULL, column_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
$query="INSERT INTO ptb_registrations(username,password,firstname,lastname,email,age,    gender,country) VALUES('".$username."','".$password."','".$firstname."',     '".$lastname."','".$email."','".$age."','".$gender."','".$country."')";
```